# Comprehending sentence about how SE works

Tags: meaning-in-context

Answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#) contains this sentence:

> The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions
>   with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5
>   views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after 365 days.

How to understand this sentence in this answer?

My question: Suppose I posted Question on June 1, 2015 & it got **2 upvotes** next day i.e June 2nd 2015 & it was **unanswered** with **no comments** & very **low views**. So will it stay alive on June 18 2017?

Comment: If it has two upvotes, it will be live on that date.

Comment: This isn't a bad logic question, but what is your specific English language question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming nothing else happens to your post it will not be *automatically deleted* for the two year span you are asking about.

However, a user with suitable *reputation* may delete your post.